# INAx181 where to place ref pin if IN+ and IN- are inverted

Tags: amplifier

The typical configuration for the [INA181](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina181.pdf?ts=1625203968972&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) looks like this

[image]

In this configurations the reference pin is tied to ground. But due to space constraints I can only trace the IN+ and IN- on the wrong end of the resistor

[image]

But in this configuration i don't know where to tie the reference pin, should i tie it to Vs? The INA181 is bidirectional so i know it can be done like that. I would still want the Analog out to be 0v to +3.3v of course.

Comment: I haven't looked into how the INA181 in particular works, but I would think connecting it to 3.3 V would give you an inverted signal (with *much* worse PSRR, so be careful); 3.3 volts with zero current going down towards ground as the current increases

Comment: Sense resistors are usually large enough to put a trace beneath them; are you sure you can't solve this with better layouting?

Comment: @MarcusMüller the other alternative is a very uneven trace matching, where IN+ is 10mm long and IN- is 2mm long (already lengthened to the longest possible given the space), would inverting it be worse than an uneven trace?

Comment: probably, yes, as the traces are not going to carry any significant current, so their noise effect would be negligible.

Comment: These are kelvin sense terminals, they don't need to be laid out as carefully since they have zero (ideally) current in them.

Comment: @Hearth its the first i have heard of that term, how far can i push what you have said? will something as extreme as 50mm and 2mm traces will still be fine?

Comment: Given the INA181's pedestrian bandwidth of 350kHz, yes, 50mm would still be fine. Trace length does not have to be matched in the slightest for frequencies that are this low.

Comment: The need to match lengths is only relevant at high speeds. And by high I mean hundreds of MHz, orders of magnitude higher than what you're working with. Of course, the longer the trace is the more noise it can pick up, so you should keep them short if possible, but that's not related to *mismatch*, just absolute length. And most of that noise is high-frequency stuff that you can probably filter out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the datasheet for the INAx181 "Bidirectional, Low- and High-Side Voltage Output, Current-Sense Amplifiers" section 8.4.2 "Unidirectional Mode", this sense amp can detect either positive current with the REF connected to ground or negative current with the REF connected to the device power (Vs).  The output polarity will be opposite, with zero current output near 0V when REF connected to ground, and zero current output near Vs when REF at Vs. Assuming the current being measured only flows in one direction, either configuration can work if the downstream measuring device doesn't care about the polarity of the amp output.

Big picture, make sure you look at the PCB layout examples in datasheet section 11.2, where the recommended circuit layout fits on just the surface layer. If the relative position of IN+/IN- amp pins to the sense resistor is awkward, then try rotating the sense resistor 180 degrees or consider swapping the placement of the sense resistor with the amp and then rotating the amplifier circuit. In my experience, playing more with the placement is often time well spent to improve or simplify the layout.